# blender --python-console result in a blank Blender window

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I wished to use gnome-terminal running a python shell to do things in blender. Is this normal?

Ubuntu 14.04, Blender 2.69, installed from Ubuntu software center. [image: snapshot]

Comment: Interesting, never tried that. But why do you need that without other interface (at least text editor to save scripts and possibility to have more than one interactive console)?